# Value for calculated property only if bit value equals true

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-4, entity, calculated-field

If I am going to have a page that displays Ingredients that are marked IsProduct on one page and use the Ingredient name to generate an image url value.

And then on another page use ingredients that are not marked IsProduct. Is there anything I could do so that when I display the ingredients that are not marked IsProduct that they will not shot a URL value for ProductImage, because it's not a product.

Is there something I should be doing in the class? or since it's a calculated value shuld I just be doing it when I'm writing the items to the page.

```
    namespace XXX.Models
    {
        public class Ingredient
        {
            public int IngredientID { get; set; }
            [StringLength(50), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
            public string IngredientNameEn { get; set; }
            [StringLength(50), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
            public string IngredientNameEs { get; set; }
            [Column(TypeName = "varchar(Max)")]
            public string IngredientDescriptEn { get; set; }
            [Column(TypeName = "varchar(Max)")]
            public string IngredientDescriptEs { get; set; }
            [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
            public bool IsProduct { get; set; }

            public string ProductImage
            {
                get { return IngredientNameEs.Replace(" ", string.Empty) + ".jpg"; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit confusing.  I think you are asking for a way to generate an URL for a valid product, and hide/disable the URL for a non product.

Outside the issue of which area of MVC should have this logic...

The code can be the same

```
    string url == string.Empty;
    if (model.IsProduct)
    {
        var builder = new UriBuilder();
        builder.  { populate the needed properties ,  model.ProductImage}
        url = builder.ToString();
    }
```